Movie about a stranded colony ship
I saw a space/sci-fi movie on Nexflix 5-10 years ago, and I can't remember the name for the life of me.
Details as best as I can remember are:

The main character is a crew member on a colony ship. They wake up alone at the beginning of the movie. I believe they knew they were on a colony ship, but I remember there was some confusion about their situation right from the start.

They believe that the ship is lost in deep space because their sensors either don't work, or can't identify anything. They cannot see any stars out of the ships windows.

As the movie progresses, more people are discovered. There are fighting factions throughout the ship.

The ships reactor was either sabotaged or started a self-destruct sequence

Near the end of the movie, the stasis pods are released from the ship, hoping that they would eventually be found by someone.

The ending is the part that I remember the most



It turns out that the colony ship had actually crash landed on its destination planet generations earlier. The various factions of people turned out to be the descendants of the original colonists, unaware of their situation. I don't remember why the sensors didn't work, but the ship was partially submerged under water, which is why they couldn't see anything out of the windows. When the pods were released from the ship, they floated to the surface.


The ending especially sounds like Pandorum (2009).  Quoting from the plot summary on Wikipedia:

Nadia observes bioluminescent ocean life through the windows, and the computer displays that 923 years have elapsed since the mission launched. The ship reached Tanis 800 years ago and landed itself in the ocean. Bower hallucinates a mutant attack and breaks a window. As water pours into the ship, Nadia and Bower climb into a hypersleep pod and eject it. The flood triggers an emergency protocol which ejects the remaining 1,211 untainted pods to the surface, while Gallo and the remaining mutants drown. Bower and Nadia surface near a lush coastline, and they witness the other pods ascend.

